# making sample program in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

i am making a sample program in hibernate follow this tutorial:
http://www.myeclipseide.com/documentation/quickstarts/hibernateintroduction/

using reverse engineering, i have created this method.
EventsDAO.java:

```
public Events findById(com.hibernate.EventsId i) {
    log.debug("getting Events instance with id: " + i);
    try {
        Events instance = (Events) getSession().get(
                "com.hibernate.Events", i);
        return instance;
    } catch (RuntimeException re) {
        log.error("get failed", re);
        throw re;
    }
}
```

and calling from main class makiing this method:

```
private static void listEvents()
{
    EventsDAO dao= new EventsDAO();
    Events events= dao.findById(1);
    printEvents("Printing User,", events);
dao.getSession().close();
}
```

it give me error on : Events events= dao.findById(1);
because here, i am passing int. and in EventsDAO.java, its type is EventsID.

please suggest.

as surlac suggest,
now it is giving exception: 
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): com.hibernate.Events

```
private static void addEvents()
{
    Events events= new Events();
    events.setUid(1);
    events.setName("abc");
    events.setDuration(123);
    EventsDAO dao= new EventsDAO();
    Transaction tx=dao.getSession().beginTransaction();
dao.save(events);
tx.commit();
dao.getSession().close();
}
```

it is giving exception on this line:

```
dao.save(events);
```

Here is Events.hbm.xml file: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<!-- 
    Mapping file autogenerated by MyEclipse Persistence Tools
-->

<hibernate-mapping>

    <class name="com.hibernate.Events" table="EVENTS" schema="APP">

        <composite-id name="id" class="com.hibernate.EventsId">

            <key-property name="uid" type="java.lang.Long">
                <column name="UID" />

            </key-property>

            <key-property name="name" type="java.lang.String">
                <column name="NAME" length="20" />

            </key-property>

            <key-property name="duration" type="java.lang.Integer">
                <column name="DURATION" />
            </key-property>

        </composite-id>

    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>`

please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use Integer as an ID, unless you use composite keys:

```
    public Events findById( java.lang.Integer id) {
        log.debug("getting Events instance with id: " + id);
        try {
            Events instance = (Events) getSession()
                    .get("com.hibernate.Events", id);
            return instance;
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            log.error("get failed", re);
            throw re;
        }
    }
```

Comment: please review, one exception are also coming

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the [tutorial](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/tutorial.html) isn't calling for an Event?

Wait - now I see your problem.  Your tutorial is from Rose India.  I'd stick to the source and use the Hibernate tutorial from JBoss.

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Event {
    private Long id;

    private String title;
    private Date date;

    public Event() {}

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    private void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```